# How to make timestamp show up in EST format

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone, timestamp

Here is the code I am using currently.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo '<th>'; echo date('h:i T M-j-y', strtotime($requesttimedb)); echo '</th>';
```

$requesttimedb comes straight from the database.

My code is currently showing:

01:00 EDT May-26-13

However, the data was really submitted at 02:00 EST May-26-13.
How can I change the timezone from EDT to EST?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken.  The Eastern time zone in the USA, `America/New_York` transitions between "Eastern Standard Time" (EST) and "Eastern Daylight Time" (EDT).  For 2013, EDT is in effect March 10th 2:00 AM, through November 3rd 2:00 AM.

So your date in May, would certainly be in EDT.

Comment: Ok.  But the information was submitted at 2:00PM my time.  It is showing 1:00 EDT.  How can I make it show 2:00?

Comment: When you "my time", what TZ are you in?  Are you  in EDT or some special part of ET that does not observe northern hemisphere EDT, or something else?

Comment: @alfredo.  What city are you in?

Comment: Atlantic City.  It is currently 3:47AM EST as I am writing this.  However, if I were to submit any data into that table, the time would show as 2:47AM EDT.

Comment: @alfredo - I think perhaps you are confused about time zones in general.  Atlantic City is in the `Eastern Time Zone`, and is currently in `Eastern Daylight Time`, the same as the rest of the zone.  It won't be in `Eastern Standard Time` until DST ends in November.  [See here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=2222).  `America/New_York` is the correct IANA zone id.

Comment: Ok.. Even with that said, how can I get the accurate time?  The time it is currently using is 1 hour behind.

Comment: Linux or Windows?  And what time zone is your computer set to?  On Windows be sure to check the "automatically adjust for DST" box in the time zone settings window.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the date is coming directly from the database, and so I'll assume you're using a SQL server, if this is the case, I suggest you set the `'timezone'` using the SQL command string `SET time_zone='timezone'`